# How to let value in child and parent component same all the time?

Tags: typescript, angular

Is it possible to let `submitted` in the child component equal with `submitted` in the parent component all the time? Thanks

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: `
        child:{{submitted}} 
  `
})
class ChildCmp {
    @Input('submitted') submitted: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.submitted = true;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <child-cmp [submitted]="submitted"></child-cmp>
    parent:{{submitted}} 
  `,
    directives: [ChildCmp]
})
class App {
    submitted: boolean;
}
bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: You have accepted below thats fine. But whats the wrong in your code. Do you know that? Your code is also working except the fact that you have forgotten to put `export` keyword I guess.

Comment: @micronyks thank you for help. It is my fault that code in my question is not clear. I will update my question to make it clear. See this: they are not equal now: http://plnkr.co/edit/5WOc85NcAwlgI5VZBSkq?p=preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup two-way model binding:

```
<child-cmp [(submitted)]="submitted"></child-cmp>
```

Child Comp:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: `
        {{submitted}} <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  `
})
class ChildCmp {
    @Input('submitted') submitted: boolean;
    @Output('submittedChange') submittedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        this.submittedChange.emit(this.submitted);
    }
}
```